# React native update template

Tags: react-native, templates

I started my project with a template:

`react-native init myApp --template`[ez-devs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-template-ez-devs)

The template has upgraded and I would like to know if there is a way to upgrade my project without be manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

In a word, no. You'll have to do it manually.

## Templates

The templating system is quite *dumb* it basically creates a new react-native project and then copies the files that are included in the template and then installs the dependencies that have been listed.

As you will undoubtably updated files that were included in the original template, you wouldn't want to just install it over your existing project and hope for the best. That would cause you lots of problems. You may also have installed dependencies that require linking with native code, the template wouldn't specifically know about these changes.

## Ways to upgrade

So how can you update to the new template? Well it really depends on what you have done to the project. Unfortunately there is not going to be an easy way to do it.

To see what the major changes are between the templates I would look at the files included in the release that you are currently using, and the release that you plan to use and create a `diff` this can be done using the following command

`diff -ur b a > ba.diff`

where `a` and `b` are the directories that you are comparing.

Unfortunately the template that you are using doesn't create releases on their github https://github.com/maykonmichel/react-native-template-ez-devs/releases

You could attempt to download them off of their npm page https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-template-ez-devs .

Ultimately you can compare the changes on their [github](https://github.com/maykonmichel/react-native-template-ez-devs/commits/master) by looking at the commit history, you could look at the `changelog` if it existed, you can also look at the dependency versions that they are using and see if they have differed from the ones that you have used.

You can use github to do your [compare](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/#comparing-commits)
Here is an example of the comparison between the most recent commit and one from a few days before.
https://github.com/maykonmichel/react-native-template-ez-devs/compare/f4ffa06..04a1b8c

Comment: Thank you so much! Although it wasn't what I expected, it helps a lot and answered my question.